# Registered Symbol not getting inserted as-is in table

Tags: sql, oracle, unicode, oracle10g

I am working on Oracle 10gR2.

The character set for DB is as below:
NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET AL16UTF16
NLS_CHARACTERSET AL32UTF8.

I am getting data to be processed in TXT files. The first step in processing this data is creating external tables based on these flat files. One of the fields (and the columns in DB) in the flat file has String data, which contains ® (registered symbol). This character is visible in the txt file, but when I check the external table, the character is saved as �

I have modified the encoding of the IDE to UTF-8, where I am seeing the output of the query.

The data type for the column is: COL NVARCHAR2(1000)

Please suggest as to what could be causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally this is caused by incorrect setting of the NLS_LANG environment variable.  The NLS_LANG variable must tell oracle the encoding you are using for your data.  If the NLS_LANG is unset, oracle assumes ASCII text (and your symbol is non-ascii).

If your data is UTF-8, try:

NLS_LANG=.AL32UTF8

For windows/iso try

NLS_LANG=.WE8ISO8859P15

You NEED to determine the encoding of your text file first.  Use a hex editor to determine of the (R) symbol is UTF-8 or not.

Comment: The NLS_LANG parameter on the Linux box, where the text files are stored, is already correctly set:export NLS_LANG="American_America.AL32UTF8"

Comment: Can anyone suggest something else?

Comment: Thanks! I figured that the character set encoding of the file is incorrect and that is what was causing character set conversion